# Redefinition is not allowed in gcc10+ but is allowed in gcc7-9

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, language-lawyer

The following code will fail in gcc10 and above, but passed in gcc7 to gcc9.

I'm wondering why? Could anyone help me?

You can try here: https://godbolt.org/ (switch compiler versions in the right-side panel)

```cpp
template <typename R>
inline constexpr bool foo = true;
template <typename R>
inline constexpr bool foo = false;

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

In gcc10 and above, the error message is:

```
<source>:5:23: error: redefinition of 'template<class R> constexpr const bool foo'
    5 | inline constexpr bool foo = false;
      |                       ^~~
<source>:3:23: note: 'template<class R> constexpr const bool foo<R>' previously declared here
    3 | inline constexpr bool foo = true;
      |                       ^~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:5:23: error: redefinition of 'template<class R> constexpr const bool foo'
    5 | inline constexpr bool foo = false;
      |                       ^~~
<source>:3:23: note: 'template<class R> constexpr const bool foo<R>' previously declared here
    3 | inline constexpr bool foo = true;
      |                       ^~~
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to compile? Seems like a bug in older gcc versions.

Comment: fwiw there is a "conformance view" https://godbolt.org/z/efabh7o5v

Comment: @ChrisMM I'm not expecting it to compile. Would you please share the bug link with me? I searched a lot but couldn't find it.

Comment: @ChrisMM I think I find it: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92576

Comment: @LixinWei Also for future purposes, try your code on different compilers also and you'll get an idea about the program. For example this code will not compile in clang and msvc and latest gcc which indicates that it was a gcc bug which was fixed by gcc. So there is no point in asking the question here. You could have just searched bugzilla for a gcc bug.

Answer (score 2):

The program is **ill-formed** as per [basic.def.odr]

From [basic.def.odr]:

> One-definition rule
>
> 1. Each of the following is termed a definable item:
>
> - a templated entity
>
> **No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any definable item.**

And since a variable template is a templated entity, the translation unit cannot have more than one definition of it.

---

This was an old gcc [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92576) which has since been fixed.

Comment: is it ill formed-ndr ? Is the compiler reuqired to diagnose it?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ODR violations are undefined behavior. I will update tge answer.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Upon reading more, I think it is ill formed(with diagnostic) as I can't find anything saying it is IFNDR in the standard. Though as [basic.def.odr] doesn't say anything about it being IFNDR, It seems to me it is ill formed only.

Comment: i believe it is ifndr when two definitions in different translation units do not match, while redefinition is a plain error

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But here the definitions are in the same translation unit so that section where standard says it is IFNDR doesn't apply here.

Comment: yes. redefinition in the same translation unit is not ifndr i think

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes exactly. Also I read [temp.res] but there also couldn't find anything that would make this IFNDR. Maybe you can give a look at [temp.res] and see if I missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by myself.

It's a bug fixed in gcc10.

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92576

Comment: This is not a good answer. Just giving a link to the bug and saying it was fixed doesn't add any useful information because we already know from the question that it was fixed. Also why it was a bug is not answered here.